# Enable wifi adapter on Linux Mint 14 Cinnamon

Tags: linux-mint

I just installed Linux Mint 14 Cinnamon on my laptop, but I can't find where to connct with wifi, I Googled about it and I found that I've to enable my wifi adapter in Software Sources, so I did enable it and then I restared my laptop, but this didn't solve my problem. When I open Software Sources again I find that my wifi adapter is not enabled.

When I log in to my session, I get a notification which says :

> **Network**  Disconnected - you are now offline

My wifi adapter is a: BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY

This is what I get when I run the command `iwconfig` :

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

When I tried to install this package firmware-b43-installer_015-14_all.deb, I got this message :

> Selecting previously unselected package firmware-b43-installer.
>  
>   (Reading database ... 139679 files and directories currently
>   installed.) 
>  Unpacking firmware-b43-installer (from
>   .../firmware-b43-installer_015-14_all.deb) ... 
>  dpkg: dependency
>   problems prevent configuration of firmware-b43-installer: 
>   firmware-b43-installer depends on b43-fwcutter (>= 1:015-14); however:
>   Package b43-fwcutter is not installed.
>  
>  dpkg: error processing
>   firmware-b43-installer (--install):  dependency problems - leaving
>   
> unconfigured Errors were encountered while processing: 
>   firmware-b43-installer

After that I installed `b43-fwcutter`, and then I tried to install the package `firmware-b43-installer_015-14_all.deb` but I got this error :

> An unsupported BCM4312 Low-Power (LP-PHY) device was found. Use b43
>   LP-PHY firmware (firmware-b43-lpphy-installer package) instead.

So I removed firmware-b43-installer_015-14_all.deb using Synaptic Package Manager, And then I installed the package `firmware-b43-lpphy-installer`, but I got this message :

> (Reading database ... 139686 files and directories currently installed.) 
>   Unpacking firmware-b43-lpphy-installer (from .../firmware-b43-lpphy-installer_4.174.64.19-4_all.deb) ... 
>   Setting up firmware-b43-lpphy-installer (4.174.64.19-4) ...
>   --2013-04-13 18:52:14--  http://downloads.openwrt.org/sources/broadcom-wl-4.178.10.4.tar.bz2
>   Resolving downloads.openwrt.org (downloads.openwrt.org)... failed:
>   Name or service not known.
>    wget: unable to resolve host address `downloads.openwrt.org' 
>   dpkg: error processing firmware-b43-lpphy-installer (--install):  subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 4 
>   Errors were encountered while processing:  firmware-b43-lpphy-installer

Comment: please post the output of `iwconfig`.

Comment: @terdon see the modification I've made

Comment: Wow, they have made an installer for a network device driver that needs to download something else to install. Smart... OK, I read [here](http://www.linuxwireless.org/en/users/Drivers/b43?highlight=%28BCM4312%29#Supported_devices) (have a look at that site, it is very useful) that the device is supported by the `wl` module. Try loading it with `sudo modprobe wl` and then run `iwconfig` again. Any difference?

Answer (score 1):

According to this page, you should install the broadcom drivrs. If you can connect your laptop using an ethernet cable, open a terminal and run

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

If you don't have access to a wired connection, get online using whatever method you used to post here and download the installer from [here](http://mirror.anl.gov/pub/ubuntu//pool/multiverse/b/b43-fwcutter/firmware-b43-installer_015-14_all.deb). You can then install it using

```
sudo dpkg -i firmware-b43-installer_015-14_all.deb
```

After that, restart and your wireless should work.

Comment: sorry, but it didn't worked, please see the modification I've made

Comment: The error is telling you that you need to install another package as well. According to the errors you posted, you need the package `b43-fwcutter` download it from http://packages.ubuntu.com and install it as described in my answer. Is connecting your computer with a wire not possible?

Comment: no, unfutunatly I don't have a wire, I'll try what you said.

Comment: please see my modifications

Answer (score 0):

For my similar model card, I needed the bcmwl- pkgs, the broadcom-sta pkgs, and the b43 one for it to work.